# timeout error in ASP.Net application

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, asp.net-4.0, asp.net-3.5

I have set time out as 240 minuts in below places.

1. idle time out option application pool
2. session time out in Web.config
3. by changing sesstion time in Global configuration of the application.

Still sometime facing issue of application timeout, this is not coming on regular basis.
Is there any seession timeout setting i left?
Pleasde suggest if i can handle the application session time out in a better way.

Comment: Set CommandTimeOut=0 in your Query or stored procedure whatever u use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we deal with huge amount of data, generally it may occur TIMEOUT problem...
in those situations Take care of 3 things ( problem will be almost solved )

1. put the connection timeout property in Connection string
   string connstring=" Data Source=localhost;User ID=sa; pwd=secret; Initial catalog=nothwind;connect timeout=900;";
2. set the command timeout for the SqlCommand Object
   com.CommandTimeout=0; // this will makes Command to execute unlimited seconds
3. Now .... last but not the least... in the form unload function
   destroy the connection object
   conn.Dispose();

Comment: Hi Arun : Thanks for the response, but your suggesion is all about connection timeout and all setting you mentioned is someway related to connection timeout. But issue i am facing with seession time out.

Answer (score -1):

Something like:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
     <sessionState timeout="20"></sessionState>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

should see you right